# Appending NaN to a Dataframe if variable is not defined

Tags: python, dataframe

I am using a code to read a dict and then calculate some variables and append it in a df in last. I am using this type of thing to calculate values.

```
try:
    most_visited_city = sorted_cities[-1]
    per_visit_max_city = 100 * cities[sorted_cities[-1]]['count'] / float(total_visits)
    if total_visits > 1:        
        avg_visit_gap_max_city = cities[sorted_cities[-1]]['sum of visit gap']/float(total_visits-1)


    secod_max_visited_city = sorted_cities[-2]
    per_visit_2ndmax_city = 100 * cities[sorted_cities[-2]]['count'] / float(total_visits)
    if total_visits > 1:        
        avg_visit_gap_2ndmax_city = cities[sorted_cities[-2]]['sum of visit gap']/float(total_visits-1)


    third_max_visited_city = sorted_cities[-3]
    per_visit_3rdmax_city = 100 * cities[sorted_cities[-3]]['count'] / float(total_visits)
    if total_visits > 1:        
        avg_visit_gap_3rdmax_city = cities[sorted_cities[-3]]['sum of visit gap']/float(total_visits-1)


except IndexError:
    pass
```

and then append like this.

```
df = df.append({'mac_address': mac, 'Last Seen' : last_seen ,'total no. of visits': total_visits, 'Percentage visit to max visited City': per_visit_max_city, 'Percentage visit to second max visited City': per_visit_2ndmax_city, 'Percentage visit to third max visited City': per_visit_3rdmax_city, ignore_index=True)
```

SO it Gives me `NameError: name 'per_visit_2ndmax_city' is not defined` for some row which is obvious. So I tried defining a function to Return its value if it is already defined else Define that variable and return Nan to that. I tried doing that by a function.

```
def ret(x):
    try:
        x
    except NameError:
        return None 
    else:
        return x
```

and then doing this

```
df = df.append({'mac_address': mac, 'Last Seen' : last_seen ,'total no. of visits': total_visits, 'Percentage visit to max visited City': ret(per_visit_max_city), 'Percentage visit to second max visited City': ret(per_visit_2ndmax_city), 'Percentage visit to third max visited City': ret(per_visit_3rdmax_city), ignore_index=True)
```

Didn't worked Any help on this. I am using Python2.7

Answer (score 1):

Numpy NaN is distinct from the generic Python None.

Try this:

```
def ret(x):
    try:
        x
    except NameError:
        return numpy.nan
    else:
        return x
```